# Server or router assigns ip address

Tags: networking, router

Im new to networking,If I have a window server and in that server I have a normal soho router, will that server assign the ip address to each device? or will that router do it. What I've learned is that the server is suppose to be the DHCP but sometimes if you plug a router directly in the server it kicks the server off and the router starts to assign the ip address. If that is so, how would you fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most routers will take on the role of a `DHCP` Server out-of-the-box. That is, they will distribute ip addresses to whatever `DHCP` Client requests an address.

By default, a Windows server will not have set up a fully configured `DHCP` Server.

By default a Windows machine (either client or server) and most other networked devices will have set their network interface to be a `DHCP` Client.

Therefore, by simply plugging in your Windows server to one of your router's LAN ports will make the router set the Windows server's network interface to the next available ip address using `DHCP`.

If you were to connect more devices to the router's LAN ports it will still be the router that assigns those extra devices an ip address.

Ideally you want only one `DHCP` server in your network.

Also, if you want your Windows server to always have the same ip address you can do two things:

- Log in to the router and set a fixed ip address for your Windows server network card's unique `MAC address`.
- Modify the router's `DHCP` range (e.g. from .10 to .200) so it leaves some addresses free (e.g. .1 to .9 and from .201 to .254). Then set your Windows server network card's fixed `IPV4` address to a fixed address (e.g. .210). You may also need to set a `DNS` server then.

This is only briefly skimming the subject of `IPV4` networks, `DHCP` and friends so when you have some time try to read the wikipedia pages for them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

Comment: So im assuming I can change the settings to make the Server assign ip address right? And whats better, to have the server assign ip address or the router

Comment: Yes, you can make the Windows server become a DHCP server as well but it may not be as simple as the way it's implemented on most routers. I would also suggest to place the DHCP server on that device which is going to be online the most. Be aware that every time you reboot the server (Windows Updates needs to do this every once in a while) your DHCP server will be unavailable for clients wanting an ip address. Experiment with DHCP on the server if you wish but I would go for running it on the router.

Comment: Yeah, those negative votes without comments are not very helpful. Anyhow, I hope your network is up and running, handing out IP addresses as you expect. Feel free to 'Accept' my answer if it gave you all the correct information required.

Answer (score 0):

Server assigns your public IP address, in fact it assigns your router a public IP address.
While the router assigns each device connected a local IP address.
With respect to your router, the IP address server assigns it is its IPv4 address and the addresses router assigns to its clients are IPv6 address.
When you browse the internet through your router, the router reads your requests and responds according to that IPv6 address and when the router requests something to the server, server sees it as its IPv4 address. :)